# If the text of a select option value exceeds 12 characters, cut it off followed by three dots

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the text of a select option value exceeds 12 characters, I want it to get cut off followed by three dots '...'

For example:

```
<select>
    <option>this is a long option</option>
</select>
```

In the selectbox I want it to be shows as "this is a ..." instead of the full text. How can this be achieved using jQuery.

Comment: that's not jquery's job. plain javascript: `if (str.length > 12) { str = str.substr(0,12) + '...'}`

Comment: try [This](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/), jquery ellipsis. extension to overflow for substituting with 3 dots

Comment: This is going to look strange for elements with 13 or 14 characters, because the "shortened" version is longer.

Comment: marc, if you write your answer in the answers section with the proper tags in place and the code inside the "<script></script>" I will accept it as the answer :)

Comment: David yes but for elements with more characters that cant fit inside the fixed width td which holds the select tag, it would serve a good purpose which would otherwise overflow out of its container and look very ugly

Answer (score 1):

this might be what you looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("option").text(function(i,t){
        //Optional set full text on title attr
        //$(this).attr("title", t);
        return t.length > 13 ? t.substr(0,10) + "..." : t;
    });
});
```

and the http://jsfiddle.net/6nt76ngv/

Comment: this is good. but there is an issue. when the select option changes (i.e. i click on another select option from the dropdown) this doesnt apply to that and the characters exceed 10 characters and overflow. I want this to be also applied to the current select element which i select. Can this be done? Thanks

Comment: its really hard to understand what exactly you mean. When the page loads, all `options` in all `selects`, that are in the markup will be cut off: http://jsfiddle.net/zx808ke7/
The current select element I select in this example, is cut off...
For generated options with jQuery, you had to do more... ohterwise explain more or diffrent! :)

Comment: Or is this maybe a browser issue? Which browser are you looking in?

Answer (score 1):

Insert the following in **$(document).ready(function{});**

```
$(".legend-sel option").each(function(){
if($(this).text().length > 12)
    $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0,12)+"...");
});
```

I think you are looking for something like this:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dce62q76/2/)

Comment: this works also.. but again the issue is that when the the select option changes after page load, i.e. i select another option from the dropdown list, this script doesnt apply to that and it exceeds the 10 characters quota. I want this to be applied to that too so the select element never overflows from its container. Thanks

Comment: @alex can you please specify, what do you mean by "doesn't apply to that"? Are you saying that the size of selected option should be 10 in select box after selection instead of 12?

Comment: no. since i am using this code on a <select> tag. when i click on the options inside the select tag the select value takes the value of the option i just clicked on, but the option characters arent reduced to 12.